# Real-world examples of populating a GWT CellTable using a clean MVP pattern?

Tags: gwt, mvp

We are using the GWT-Presenter framework and attempting to use CellTable to put together an updateable grid. It seems as though several of the GWT constructs for CellTable don't lend themselves to easily breaking up the logic into clean view and presenter code.

Examples: 1) Within the View's constructor, the CellTable is defined and each column is created by anonymous inner classes that extend the Column class to provide the onValue() method. 2) The FieldUpdater interface must be implemented to provide logic to execute when a user alters data in a cell. This seems like it would best fit in the Presenter's onBind() method, but FieldUpdaters often need access to the Cell or Column which belong in the view. CellTable does not have accessor methods to get hold of the Columns or Cells, so it seems the only way for the Presenter to get them is for me to create a multitude of member variables on the View and accessors on my Display interface.

Can anyone provide good examples for dealing with CellTable in GWT-Presenter or a comparable MVP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to avoid binding of Model class with View? i tried doing that for cellTable but it was becoming confusing to maintain code so i decided to let Model class couple with View. you can avoid this coupling by some generic arguments while creating view..

-Saket

Answer (score 3):

I think the main point of GWT MVP is that Presenters (Activities in 2.1) do not depend on View implementation, so that you can easily swap in mock Views for easy testing.

Further, it's OK to have Views that depend on Presenters (= call presenter methods), but not vice versa (well yes, but via interface).

Usually I just keep Presenter reference inside View, so that FieldUpdater anon inner classes can call methods in Presenter. You could put this methods in an interface, but it would make no sense since there is only one version of given type of Presenter.

Or, if you want to have things more decoupled, then just have View send a GWT Event which Presenter listens to.